# Facebook добавляет параметры к внешним ссылкам. Есть ли способ обхода?

Tags: .htaccess, url, facebook

Если разместить (например, в посте) ссылку вида `https://exemple.org` то, к ней добавляются параметры, она приобретает примерно следующий вид `https://example.org/?fbclid=IwAR0HThXmht23SDCHubwpWNcajg3XSVLfTJRN84h4eJjUgNY4vvLZodb8m6c` и понятное дело, ведёт совсем не туда, куда нужно, а именно на страницу ошибки.

Существует ли какой-то обходной путь? Например, в .htaccess указать какую-нибудь инструкцию, чтобы резало всё, начиная с `/?`. Или чтобы редиректило на то, что нужно.

Comment: что-то не совсем нормально, если левый get-параметр прям у вас ошибку генерирует

Comment: это же просто дополнительный get-параметр. если вы настроили свои скрипты так, что этот параметр «ведёт совсем не туда», то, похоже, совершили ошибку. исправьте её, и не придётся влиять на конфигруацию http-сервера.

Comment: @teran, ну кидает на страницу 404, в списке роутов то нет такого

Comment: get-параметры на роуты влиять бы не должны

Answer (score 0):

В общем накопала вот такое:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=302,L,NE]
```

У меня всё работает блестяще. Кто вообще не шарит, просто скопируйте это в свой .htaccess :)